# App does not open by sliding lock screen (without passcode) after Apple Push Notification arrives

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have configured APNS in my app current iOS version is iOS 8.

The problem is after my application got terminated or After I kill the app. Push notification arrived, sound and alert work fine, now when I slide the Screen to unlock my iPhone nothing happens but If I slides the push notification the application opens and everything works fine.

I have set content-available to 1 in Push Notification.

As long as application is in Background it works fine.But when I kill the app and push notification arrives and I slide the lock screen(without tapping on push notification) Application does not open

Following is the code of Appdelegate function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions which concerns with push notification.

```
 NSDictionary *remoteNotifiInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (remoteNotifiInfo) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteNotifiInfo];
    }
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This code is work for you ? @Muhammad Nayab

Comment: @JayBhalani I will respond to you if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your `AppDelegate.h` file :

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]!=nil)
{
    NSDictionary * aPush =[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:aPush];
}
```

Try this code it's work for me. I hope its work for you.

Comment: In case application is in Background it works but when I kill the app and then push arrives and I slide the screen(without tapping push notification) application does not open unless I tap app icon.

Comment: without tapping push notification it's not possible to open app .  Different different type of PushNotification is Available we can not manage it.  @MuhammadNayab

Comment: one more thing I killed the app. Push notification arrived I slide the view as you said the app won't open so I tapped the app icon the method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" got called and then [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] returned "nil" this was little bit unexpected I mean there was a push notification but why this returned nil? and where does that push notification went?

Comment: `[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] `returned "nil" because you do not click PushNotification. you click `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.  without you `PushNotification` click it will be return `nil` @MuhammadNayab

Comment: Welcome any time @Muhammad Nayab